# Apply a sequence of functions to value and get the final result

Tags: scala

I wish to apply a sequence of functions to an object (each of the functions may return the same or modified object) and get the ultimate result returned by the last function.

Is there an idiomatic Scala way to turn this (pseudocode):

```
val pipeline = ListMap(("a" -> obj1), ("b" -> obj2), ("c" -> obj3))
```

into this?

```
val initial_value = Something("foo", "bar")
val result = obj3.func(obj2.func(obj1.func(initial_value)))
```

The `pipeline` is initialized at runtime and contains an undetermined number of "manglers".

I tried with `foreach` but it requires an intermediate `var` to store the result, and `foldLeft` only works on types of `ListMap`, while the initial value and the result are of type `Something`.

Thanks

Comment: Is input and output type of each function the same?

Comment: What is the signature of obN.func? (bascally the same as @ghik's comment)

Comment: @ghik, each function accepts and returns a `Something`: `def func(foo: Something): Something`

Comment: "foldLeft only works on types of ListMap, while the initial value and the result are of type Something." Why is this a problem? You call foldLeft on pipeline, passing inital_value as the initial value, and modify the accumulator in each step by calling the next function from the pipeline

Comment: as I understand you just need to get rid of keys of your `ListMap` first `pipeline.values.foldLeft(initial_value)((a, f) => f.func(a))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 pipeline.foldLeft(initial_value){case (acc, (k,obj)) => obj.func(acc)}
```

No idea why pipeline contains pairs, though.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get `foldLeft` working now. The pairs in the pipeline are because I will later pass the pipeline itself into another function which may need to access specific processors by their names.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think ListMap makes any guarantees about the order of elements  - it is at liberty to shuffle them every time you produce a updated one. If you wanted something that preserves the insertion order, you may prefer LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming input and output types are the same, I'd go with a `reduceLeft` and composition by `andThen`:

```
def pipe[A](a: A, funcs: List[A => A]): A = funcs.reduceLeft(_ andThen _)(a)
```

Comment: You want `reduceLeft`. For `reduce` "The order in which operations are performed on elements is unspecified and may be nondeterministic." And `pipeline` isn't a list of A=>A so can't be used directly.

Comment: Upvoted for taking  a different approach of composing functions to get a function that does what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think foldLeft is the right choice:

```
val pipeline = List("a"-> func1, "b"-> func2, "c"-> func3)
...
val result = pipeline.foldLeft(initial_value) {case (acc,(key,func)) => func(acc)}
```

Comment: Pipeline isn't a List, but a ListMap. That still supports foldLeft though

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your keys, first:

```
pipeline.values.foldLeft(initial_value)((a, f) => f.func(a))
```

Comment: Does `values` of a ListMap preserve order? I think it probably does but the scaladoc doesn't say

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Is it really matters? func's from OP's question may be commutative. However, from the sources I can surely say that it preserves order actually. Every Node has next method, which returns previous one, this next is used by iterator, returned by values method, see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.scala#L1

Comment: It's pretty unlikely the functions would be commutative. In fact, they'd have to be identity or inverses of one another for that to work. You need f(g(i)) === g(f(i)) for all g and f in pipeline's functions. With more than two, that means identity only

Comment: And personally, I'd prefer to go by the contract of the doc/spec and not rely on the current implementation. Although I think the bigger issue may be how `pipeline` is constructed, not how it's used.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul But doc says nothing about preserving order inside ListMap itself (except reference to List-based structure, which should be intuitively order-preserving), so same for foldLeft. And OP is using exactly this structure. Talking about commutativity, simplest example is f = _ + 1, g = _ + 2, so it's not so unlikely as it seems :)

Comment: yes, I accept fIoldLeft has the same issue. And yes, you can have commutative functions, of course, but it's not generally true. The issue (as I said in a comment to my answer) is that ListMap is probably the wrong data structure to use here.